# Selling Partner API AMAZON (SP API) - Check If Seller Account Is Active

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to fetch orders for some of our customers using Amazon SP API:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue here is that I can't determine whether the error is due to the customer's seller account being closed or if there is another problem. I searched online but couldn't find any information. Is there a service in the SP API that I can use to check if a seller account is active?